# Phoenix nested route not being recognized by helpers

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

So I'm following along [this wonderful guide](https://medium.com/@diamondgfx/writing-a-blog-engine-in-phoenix-part-2-authorization-814c06fa7c0#.28mrmtuw5) and I've come across this issue that does not seem to be addressed.

My `web/router.ex` file looks like this:

```
defmodule Pxblog.Router do
  use Pxblog.Web, :router

  pipeline :browser do
    plug :accepts, ["html"]
    plug :fetch_session
    plug :fetch_flash
    plug :protect_from_forgery
    plug :put_secure_browser_headers
  end

  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
  end

  scope "/", Pxblog do
    pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack

    get "/", PageController, :index
    resources "/users", UserController do
      resources "/posts", PostConroller
    end

    resources "/sessions", SessionController, only: [:new, :create, :delete]
  end

  # Other scopes may use custom stacks.
  # scope "/api", Pxblog do
  #   pipe_through :api
  # end
end
```

but I'm getting a compilation error with `undefined function user_post_path/4` when I use the helper in a template.

The line that's throwing the error is in the template `web/templates/post/edit`, and it's as follows:

```
<%= render "form.html", changeset: @changeset, action: user_post_path(@conn, :update, @user, @post) %>
```

But it's an issue in other templates even when I take that line out.

The full compilation error is:

```
== Compilation error on file web/views/post_view.ex
 ==
** (CompileError) web/templates/post/edit.html.eex:
4: undefined function user_post_path/4
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1338: :lists.foreach/2
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:117: a
nonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_comp
ilers/1
```

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: I've tried getting the repo for the guide, but it fails for other reasons that I don't want to look into (seems harder)

Comment: Can you post the line that throws this error and also the complete error message?

Comment: @Dogbert thanks for your time; edited the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spelled `PostController` wrong. I am a dumb.